# if $\operatorname{ord}(\alpha)=n_1$ and $\operatorname{ord}(\beta)=n_2$, then what is $\operatorname{ord}(\alpha\beta)$?

Tags: finite-fields, cyclic-groups

$\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$

If $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{GF}(q)$ and $\ord(\alpha)=n_1$ and $\ord(\beta)=n_2$, then what is $\ord(\alpha\beta)$ ?

**Edit:**

if $k=\ord(\alpha\beta)$ then

$$(\alpha\beta)^k=1 \Longrightarrow \alpha^k=\beta^{(-k)}  \Longrightarrow$$
$$\ord(\alpha^k)= \ord(\beta^{(-k)})= \ord(\beta^k) \Longrightarrow$$ $$\frac{n_1}{\gcd(n_1,k)}=\frac{n_2}{\gcd(n_2,k)}$$

Also it is clear that $k \mid \rm lcm (n_1,n_2)$.

Comment: I looked at your profile. I wonder, where are you from?

Comment: could you please explain what have you tried?

Comment: Because of the statement in your profile.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I've edited the post to show what I've tried. Thanks

Comment: $gcd(n_1,k)=an_1+bk$,same for $gcd(n_2,k)=cn_2+dk$

Comment: @Dimitris Thanks. But, how that helps? Is it possible to find $a,b,c,d$ for the problem? Otherwise, I don't think it would help.

Comment: If you solve for $k$ you will have that $$k=\frac {n_1n_2(c-a)}{dn_1-bn_2}$$

Comment: @Dimitris I see, but since $a,b,c,d$ are not determined, I hope a better solution exists.

Comment: Since the question really is about orders of elements in a cyclic group, I took the liberty of adding a tag. This way your question may get more (and better) answers.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi,ok i agree,but if you have to compute something with  known $a,b,c,d$ i think it will be quite handy the type for $k$.I don't think that there is something less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient information to find the order of $\alpha\beta$ exactly. Consider the following case. Assume that $n_1=n_2=p>2$ is a prime. Then it is possible that $\alpha=\beta$, in which case $\alpha\beta=\alpha^2$ is of order $p$. But it is also possible that $\alpha=\beta^{-1}$, in which case $\alpha\beta=1$ has order $1$.

Let $\nu_p(m)$ be the multiplicity of prime $p$ as a factor of $m$. The above example generalizes as follows. If $\nu_p(n_1)=\nu_p(n_2)=\ell$, then we have no way of figuring out $\nu_p(k)$. All we can say in this case is that $0\le \nu_p(k)\le\ell$. Think about this in the additive group $\Bbb{Z}_{p^\ell}$ to see that all possibilities occur.

On the other hand, if $\nu_p(n_1)\neq\nu_p(n_2)$, then we know that
$$
\nu_p(k)=\max\{\nu_p(n_1),\nu_p(n_2)\}=:\ell.
$$
Again, this is easy to see in the additive group $\Bbb{Z}_{p^\ell}$, and the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups (here $GF(q)^*$) reduces the general case to this.